# Paging Up/Down in irssi Running In The iTerm2 Terminal Emulator

Tags: macos, iterm

I can't figure out how to actually page up and down in irssi's history to see previous conversations. The majority of posts claimed that first hitting Ctl+A, then using Shft+fn+[up/down], which didn't work either.
I'm sure this is a meta-character terminal translation issue, but I have no idea where or what to start tinkering with. If anyone knows what is going on or how I can fix it, I would be ever so grateful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without Shift just: fn+[up/down]

Comment: Hey! Perfect :) Thanks. If I had 15 rep points, I'd totally up vote your answer.

Comment: and shift + fn + up/down on macbook